# TMS FNC Rich Editor Copy text and Format

Tags: delphi, tms

I am using the TMS FNC RichEditor Component.  I will add text to it, then in another form I want to take that text and format like Bold, Color, underline ect. And add it to the current RichEditor. Currently I use the code below but it only transfers the text not format.  How could I also transfer the format?

```
procedure CopyStreamToEditor(SourceEditor, TargetEditor: TTMSFNCRichEditor);
var
  Stream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    SourceEditor.SaveToStream(Stream);
    Stream.Position := 0; // Reset stream position before loading

    TargetEditor.LoadFromStream(Stream);
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```